# Automatically deploy ASP.NET Core website to Plesk - Post-deploy script cut short

Tags: asp.net-core, github, continuous-deployment, plesk, githooks

For the past days I've been trying to automate deployment of an ASP.NET Core website to a Plesk Obsidian for Windows environment. I've been struggling pretty bad with this.

In Plesk the Git extension is installed, which allows us to select a branch from which Plesk should pull files into the document root

[image: Plesk admin panel]

Here's the configuration panel

[image: Plesk git configuration panel]

I have to compile my source files before they can be deployed to the server. But the **deploy actions** script doesn't know `dotnet`. So I've setup following github action in my [github repository](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/CICD):

```
name: create-release

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - 'master'
jobs:
    build:
        name: create-release
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        steps:
            - name: Setup SSH
              uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.1
              with:
                ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
                
            - name: Setup Git Client
              run: |
                ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
                git config --global user.email "github-actions@doesnotmatter.dev"
                git config --global user.name "GitHub Actions"

            - name: Checkout
              uses: actions/checkout@v4
              
            - name: Setup .NET Core
              uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3.0.3
              with:
                dotnet-version: 7.0.400
                # Authenticates packages to push to GPR
                source-url: https://nuget.pkg.github.com/${{ github.repository_owner }}/index.json
              env:
                NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: '%NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN%'

            - name: Install dependencies
              run: dotnet restore
              env:
                NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
                  
            - name: Build
              run: dotnet publish --configuration Release
                
            - name: Test
              run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal

            # Clone this repository (deploy branch) inside the "deploy" folder
            # Before clearing out, move .git folder out of the "deploy" folder
            # Recreate deploy folder, empty
            # Move .git folder back again
            # Move publish to deploy folder
            # Push files to the "deploy" branch
            - name: Deploy
              run: |
                git clone --depth 1 --single-branch -b deploy git@github.com:${{ github.repository }}.git deploy
                mv deploy/.git deploy-.git
                rm -rf deploy
                mkdir deploy
                mv deploy-.git deploy/.git
                cd deploy
                cp -R ../bin/Release/net7.0/publish .
                git add .
                git diff --staged --quiet || git commit -m "Update Artifacts"
                git push
```

This action does the following: When github receives a commit on the `master` branch, github will build the project and push a new commit with the build result to the `deploy` branch.

I've added this webhook to my github repository, along with the SSH private key as a secret

[image: Trigger Plesk webhook from Github]

So when Plesk receives the webhook, Plesk clones the repository commit in the document root,  but **DOES NOT** stop the application pool. So the DLLs and EXEs are still locked at that point. This is why I put [my build](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/CICD/tree/deploy) in a subfolder:

[image: Deploy branch]

Then, in Plesk, we can only specify a post-checkout script. Which at the moment looks like this:

```
# Create app_offline.htm.
# This effectively unlocks the exe and dll
echo "" > app_offline.htm
# Delete files from the document root. Don't ask for confirmation (Q)
DEL /F /Q *.exe *.dll *.pdb
# With the app-pool stopped, we can now move the files to the document root
copy publish . /y
# All commands below are never executed. So the app never gets online anymore
DEL /Q app_offline.htm
DEL /Q publish
```

For some reason all commands after the copy aren't executed anymore. Does anyone know why this is happening? I've tried `COPY`, `MOVE`, `ROBOCOPY`, `XCOPY`.

With xcopy it works at first, but stops again when there's already files in the target folder (`xcopy publish . /v /s /y`)

### EDIT

The DELETE commands seems to work/not work in an alternating fashion.

I tried adding a `TIMEOUT` but then it doesn't work at all:

```
echo "" > app_offline.htm
DEL /F /Q *.exe *.dll *.pdb
xcopy publish . /v /s /y && TIMEOUT 2 && DEL /Q app_offline.htm && DEL /Q publish
```

### EDIT 2

Tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57860316/plesk-git-additional-deploy-actions-npm-not-executed). Updated deploy script

```
echo "" > C:\Inetpub\example.com\app_offline.htm
DEL /F /Q *.exe *.dll *.pdb
xcopy C:\Inetpub\example.com\publish C:\Inetpub\example.com /v /s /y
DEL /Q C:\Inetpub\example.com\app_offline.htm
DEL /Q C:\Inetpub\example.com\publish
```

But same weird behavior here. One time it works, one time doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it using the following post-deploy script

```
echo "" > .\app_offline.htm
PING -n 2 localhost
DEL /F /Q *.exe *.dll *.pdb
PING -n 2 localhost
XCOPY .\publish . /C /Q /R /S /Y
PING -n 2 localhost
DEL /Q .\app_offline.htm
DEL /Q .\publish
```

I summarized all steps [here](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/ci-cd-an-asp-net-core-application-to-plesk-azure-996a66450fba)

Comment: Thank you for your post with all the steps. Although I haven't used this answer, it has helped me so much to understand how to push the compiled web to a separate branch.